# Is there a way to print the PID of the process that called my C binary

Tags: c, bash, unix, gcc, solaris

I need to know which perl script is using my C CLI.

Using bash I can easily print "who" ran a script using:

```
CALLER=$(ps ax | grep "^ *$PPID" | awk '{print $NF}')
echo $CALLER
```

Up to now I have been using this as a wrapper but it's not ideal. Is there a way to get this information from within C?

(I'm running UNIX w/ gcc)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should look at `getpid` and `getppid` functions from `<unistd.h>`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int
main(void)
{
    printf("%ld%ld", (long)getpid(), (long)getppid());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `getppid`. See `man 2 getppid`, [here's](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpid) the linux man page.

> getppid() returns the process ID of the parent of the calling process

*Two* p’s because this is for the “parent process”.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`getppid()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getppid) to obtain the process id of a process' parent.